# Change range of values in a 2d array with lists in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, range

In python, I have a 2D array of size 13 and each element is a list of size 16.
I want to convert all the values in this array to a different range using the following.

```
((old value - old min)/(old max - old min)) * (new max - new min) + new min
```

I am using something similar to this -

```
a_list = [1, 2, 3]

multiplied_list = [element * 2 for element in a_list]

print(multiplied_list)
```

I get the following error

```
"unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int' "
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Provide code which has error. this code working perfectly.

Comment: `a_list` is probably a list of lists

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured out, I had to convert the 2D array from list to a float array using numpy.array()

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, I had to convert the 2D array from list to a float array using numpy.array()